# Проблема с создание функции SQL-SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

Мне необходимо написать функцию, которая делает следующее: Определяет тип выпусков заданного журнала в зависимости от количества публикаций в нем. Если количество публикаций больше 2 и меньше 4, тип — насыщенный, если меньше или равно 2, тип — ненасыщенный, если больше или равно 4, тип — перенасыщенный. Результат примерно такой:

**номер | тип | кол-во публикаций**

Выпуск№1 | ненасыщенный | 2

Выпуск№2 | насыщенный | 3

Выпуск№3 | насыщенный | 3

Выпуск№4 | перенасыщенный | 5

Выпуск№5 | перенасыщенный | 6

Выпуск№6 | ненасыщенный | 1

Таблицы создаются следующим образом

```
CREATE table Журналы( 
   id_журнала INT identity  PRIMARY KEY ,
   Название VarChar(100) NOT NULL,
   Издатель VArChar(100) NOT NULL
);
CREATE table Выпуски_журналов( 
   Индентификатор_выпуска INT identity PRIMARY KEY,
   id_журнала INT references Журналы,
   Номер_выпуска INT NOT NULL ,
   Год INT 
); 
CREATE table Публикации( 
   Код_публикации INT identity PRIMARY KEY,
   Индентификатор_выпуска int references Выпуски_журналов,
   Название_публикации VArChar(100) NOT NULL ,
   Страницы INT check (Страницы>=1 and Страницы<=15) 
); 
CREATE table Авторы(
   id_автора INT identity PRIMARY KEY,
   ФИО VArChar(100) NOT NULL ,
   Дата_рождения  DATE,
   Пол VArChar(100) 
); 
CREATE table АвторПубликаций( 
  Код_публикации  int references Публикации,
  id_автора int references Авторы
);
```

Я пробовал создать данную функцию

```
create function c(@dep int) returns int as
begin
    return (select count(Код_публикации) from Журналы,Выпуски_журналов,Публикации
    where (Журналы.id_журнала=Выпуски_журналов.id_журнала and Выпуски_журналов.Индентификатор_выпуска=Публикации.Индентификатор_выпуска) and Журналы.id_журнала = @dep
    group by Номер_выпуска);
end;
go
create function func(@dep int) returns varchar(45) as
begin
    if ([dbo].[c](@dep)) >= 4 return ('перенасыщенный');
    else if ([dbo].[c](@dep)) <= 2 return ('ненасыщенный');
    else return ('насыщенный');
    return '0';
end;
```

И если вам не тяжело, вы не могли бы мне объяснить, как правильно вызывать функцию в SQl-SERVER

Comment: Первая функция принимает параметр, но не использует его. Вторая совершенно бессмысленно вызывает функцию дважды, хотя достаточно одного вызова, если использовать CASE, к тому же не учитывает, что передаваемое значение может отсутствовать в таблице или быть NULL.

Comment: Зачем вам в первой функции group by ? Это уже ошибка, так как подзапрос может выдать более одного значения. У вас проблема не с созданием/использованием функций, а в первую очередь с их наполнением.

Answer (score 1):

У меня хорошее настроение, так что ловите :)

Сначала почистим за собой для повторных запусков:

```
--для тестов
USE tempdb;
GO
--чистим для перезапуска и отладки
IF OBJECT_ID('PubCnt', 'FN') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION PubCnt
IF OBJECT_ID('PubScore', 'FN') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION PubScore

GO
```

Теперь создаём наши 2 функции, на самом деле можно было и одной обойтись...

```
GO
--функция подсчёта публикаций(хотя как по мне - это лишний шаг)
CREATE FUNCTION PubCnt(@dep INT) RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
  RETURN (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM Журналы G
        JOIN Выпуски_журналов VG ON G.id_журнала = VG.id_журнала
        JOIN Публикации P ON VG.Индентификатор_выпуска = P.Индентификатор_выпуска
      WHERE G.id_журнала = @dep
  )
END
GO
--Интерпретация количества публикаций в строку
CREATE FUNCTION PubScore(@dep INT) RETURNS NVARCHAR(255) AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Score INT = dbo.PubCnt(@dep)
  RETURN (CASE 
    WHEN @Score >= 4 THEN 'перенасыщенный'
    WHEN @Score > 2 THEN 'насыщенный'
    WHEN @Score <= 2 THEN 'ненасыщенный'
    ELSE 'А что произшло?!?'
    END
  )
END

GO
```

Чистим данные, чтобы повторные запуски ничего не ломали, всё в целях отладки

```
--Чистим и таблички, но на РАБОЧЕЙ БД НЕ ЗАПУСКАТЬ!!!
DELETE FROM Публикации --SELECT * FROM Публикации
DELETE FROM Выпуски_журналов --SELECT * FROM Выпуски_журналов
DELETE FROM Журналы --SELECT * FROM Журналы
GO
```

Делаем немного тестовых данных, чтобы они +- отражали суть задачи

```
--Вот теперь добавим немного данных, иначе совсем скучно :)
INSERT Журналы VALUES
(N'Ну нет публикаций', N'Авампоф'),
(N'Парочка есть', N'Авампоф'),
(N'Три тоже неплохо', N'Ичего'),
(N'Уже круть', N'Аничего'),
(N'Перебор', N'ВсякоеБывает')

INSERT Выпуски_журналов
SELECT G.id_журнала, X, 2014+X
FROM Журналы G,(VALUES(1)/*,(2)*/)X(X)

INSERT Публикации 
SELECT VG.Индентификатор_выпуска, CA.VP, 10 
FROM Журналы G
  JOIN Выпуски_журналов VG ON G.id_журнала = VG.id_журнала
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT CONCAT('Any',N)VP FROM(
      SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT(1)))N 
      FROM Выпуски_журналов VD
    )T WHERE N <=
      CASE G.Название WHEN N'Ну нет публикаций' THEN 0
                      WHEN N'Парочка есть' THEN 2
                      WHEN N'Три тоже неплохо' THEN 3
                      WHEN N'Уже круть' THEN 4
                      WHEN N'Перебор' THEN 5
                      END
  )CA

GO
```

Ну и проверяем как это всё в итоге работает:

```
SELECT *, dbo.PubCnt(G.id_журнала)AS PubCnt, dbo.PubScore(G.id_журнала)AS PubScoreDesc
FROM Журналы G
```

Выглядит примерно так:

| id_журнала | Название | Издатель | Количество публикаций | Резюме |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 226 | Ну нет публикаций | Авампоф | 0 | ненасыщенный |
| 227 | Парочка есть | Авампоф | 2 | ненасыщенный |
| 228 | Три тоже неплохо | Ичего | 3 | насыщенный |
| 229 | Уже круть | Аничего | 4 | перенасыщенный |
| 230 | Перебор | ВсякоеБывает | 5 | перенасыщенный |